# Visual Studio Help - The "RunCommand" property is not defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio, runcommand

I'm using **Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017**. I have created a project with multiple classes. The primary class I want the application to run first has `public static void Main(string[] args)` in it.

I've set properties to the following:

- Target Framework: .NET standard 2.0
- Output type: Console Application
- Startup object: Main.Game

The error persists despite all the forums I have visited.

Answer (score 40):

I was facing this issue in my `Visual Studio 2017 15.7.2` version. The cause for this issue in my case was, unknowingly I had changed my `Asp.Net Core 2.1` Web API project output type to `Class Library`. Changing it back to `Windows Application` fixed my issue.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I did as well. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Seems odd to call a Web API proj a Windows Application bc there is no .exe, but I guess it makes more sense than Class Library

Answer (score 4):

From [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/833#issuecomment-440228858)

Try adding the following to you `<PropertyGroup>`:

```
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
<RunCommand>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath64)\..\IIS Express\iisexpress</RunCommand>
<RunArguments>/path:&quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)&quot; /port:18082</RunArguments>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Microsoft has this issue open (https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/833) for a long time, but has provided no answer.

Comment: The community has posted some workarounds there

Comment: According to that link, this issue was fixed in .NET 4.6 back in 2019: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/milestone/15 (even though I ran into it in .NET 7.0 today).

Answer (score 2):

Try changing from `netstandard2.0` to `netcoreapp2.0` for Target Framework.

Answer (score 1):

It's usual in Visual Studio.

You have to do 3 things to solve this. In some cases one is enough but sometimes three of them is required.

1. Open proj.csproj file in the root of the project (if you see no files, try to use ctrl+F to search the solution and find it)

   Try to add this `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.web">`
2. Open your project and right-click on the project main root and go properties
   then from the right block select application and the from the white box there select output type to class library.
3. Try to clean and build the entire solution again.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution contain more than one projects :
Client(Angular) project, Server(API) side project and other project.
In solution, "Single startup project", its set to Client(Angular) project, which cause issue.

I have updated and set Server side(API) project as "Single startup project".
Rebuild solution and error "RunCommand" property is not defined"resolved.

Select Solution > Property > this setting screen available.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Asp.Net project try to remove this row from csproj:

```
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the error "`...RunCommand property is not defined`" trying to *Start* (run) a project with which I previously had no issues (Visual Studio 2022).

I finally recognized that somehow my "*Startup Project*" was changed to another of my Solution's projects. Specifically, changed to a project that **IS** "*Output type: Class Library*." It took some time to discern that I had somehow changed the "*Startup Project*." I set it back to what it should have been, and was before. All is again well.