# Upgraded an older web project to new SDK-Style project format, and now I can't debug

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis

I have an older web project, started in 2017, that I've recently used the `upgrade-assistant` program to upgrade into a SDK-style project.  With the older project format, I used to debug in IIS (not ISS express).  But now the entire **Web** menu tab in the project properties is missing. Here is where it used to be:

[image]

I understand now some of these settings have been moved to a new file called `launchSettings.json`.  This is what I have currently in this file in the new SDK-style project:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Run In IIS": {
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost"
    }
  },
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I try to debug and run this profile on my project I get an error saying `Unable to run your project. The "RunCommand" property is not defined.`

[image]

Now before saying, "Go set your project output type to Windows Application, or Console Application", this web project's output type has ALWAYS been set to library.  Changing it just creates a compile time error looking for the entry point.  Here are the project type guids from the old .csproj if it clears anything up `<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>`. Its never been compiled as an EXE. The upgrade assistant has left me high and dry on this.  There must be some magic property or setting somewhere that I don't know about that allows me to debug in IIS without throwing that stupid error.

Comment: Someone likely needs access to VS source code to tell you the answer, right?

Comment: What is your project? Is this thread helpful to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852382/visual-studio-help-the-runcommand-property-is-not-define

Comment: @YurongDai I've seen this post before and It isn't quite what I need.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.